# Prometheus-- context deadline exceeded for a responsive target in prometheus UI

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

When I open the prometheus target in a browser it is responding, but in prometheus UI it is showing the error -- Get **endpoint** context line exceeded

Comment: This issue is happening only for production endpoint

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing `scrape_timeout` for the corresponding `scrape_config` section for the given target. See [docs about scrape_timeout in scrape_config section](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config). By default `scrape_timeout` is limited by `scrape_interval`.

Comment: Increased the scrape_timeout value for the target. Currently 30s for both scrape_timeout and scrape_interval.

Comment: Still have the same issue

Comment: Try logging in to the host where Prometheus is running and then use curl for loading the given scrape url. Probably, the target is unavailable from the host with Prometheus due to network configs

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same problem, and the problem is the Network.
I installed my machine on Virtualbox and activate the NAT to supply the Internet inside my master node. I turn off my NAT and use a bridge connection instead.
I do change the scrape but it's not working on my side.

NB: I don't have docker and my memory is only 4GB.